# Is there a way to simplify this ES query?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "number": [77, 55]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "xxx",
              "lte": "xxx"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Query string query: ([Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html))

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
       "query": "(number:77 AND @timestamp:[xxx TO yyy]) OR (number:55 AND @timestamp:[xxx TO yyy])"
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is this query more efficient too?

Comment: not particularly, this query string is translated to regular query eventually.

Comment: if it works please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the timestamp ranges are the same in both `should` clauses. If so, nest the `number` terms inside a `should` clause and nest this along with `range` inside a `must` clause.

```
{
    "size":0,
    "query":{
       "bool":{
          "must":[
             {
                "bool":{
                   "should":[
                      {
                         "term":{
                            "number":77
                         }
                      },
                      {
                         "term":{
                            "number":55
                         }
                      }
                   ]
                }
             },
             {
                "range":{
                   "@timestamp":{
                      "gte":"xxx",
                      "lte":"xxx"
                   }
                }
             }
          ]
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, is this query more efficient too?

Comment: `bool/should/2xterm` = `terms` see @Nishant's answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming timestamps are same and you don't need scoring,

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "number": [77, 55]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "xxx",
              "lte": "xxx"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is this query more efficient too?

Comment: Yes because we are avoiding score calculation by wrapping `terms` and `range` query under `filter` clause.

Comment: With the filter clause, the score is not calculated?

Comment: No score calculation is not done with filter clause.